# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService

Tags: selenium, grid

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
```

Tried with

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
         "E://Selenim Installations//Chrome
         Driver//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");


public void testGrid() throws MalformedURLException {

        DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities().chrome();

        dc.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);

        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");
        // URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");

        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, dc);

        driver.get("https://ui.freecrm.com/");

        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());


Expected: Driver should launch
```

Actual: Getting below error

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'RISHI', ip: '192.168.0.5', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 145 milliseconds
```

Comment: Did you start the _Selenium Grid Hub_ and _Selenium Grid Node_?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure chromedriver.exe is set to a path.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/path to/chromedriver.exe");
cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.WINDOWS);
browser = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),cap);
```

Comment: if user want to use 
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().version("2.42").setup();

instead of 
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/path to/chromedriver.exe");

then how this will be handled in capabilities or chrome option